# DOM Manipulations

Tags: javascript, html

I'm still struggling with this question.

Add an Event Handler to the li element and console.log() the name of the shirt they selected. Use JavaScript

```
<h3>Shirts</h3>
<ul id='list'>
  <li>Biker Jacket</li>
  <li>Mens Shirt</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: [StackOverflow isn't here to do your work for you](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Show us what you have tried so far. We'll gladly help you.

Comment: Looks like a Home work. Why not do yourself?

Comment: [The EventTarget method `addEventListener()` sets up a function to be called whenever the specified event is delivered to the target.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Answer (score 0):

If i get your question right, use jQuery:

```
$('li').click(function() {
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: The question doesn't state jQuery. So try to answer in vanilla Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a homework question. And that you are new to StackOverflow.

On StackOverflow you should always write pieces of code that you have attempted.

Anyways, because you are new...  I can show you 2 ways of accomplishing this.

---

> Please note that I am not so good in vanilla Javascript aswell. So
>   there is probably a better way to accomplish what you're trying.

---

**1) Inline Event Handler**

You can add inline event handlers directly to the HTML, like this:

```
<h3>Shirts</h3>
<ul id='list'>
  <li onclick='console.log(this.innerText)'>Biker Jacket</li>
  <li onclick='console.log(this.innerText)'>Mens Shirt</li>
</ul>
```

**2) Non-inline Event Handler**

The difference here is that you need to refer to the exact elements you want to add an Event Listener to. The benefit of doing this, is that you don't have to add an Event Listener manually to each list element. So the HTML stays clean.

```
var list = document.getElementById("list"); // select the parent element
var items = list.getElementsByTagName("li"); // select all <li> items in this parent element

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) { // loop through all items
    items[i].addEventListener("click", function() { // add the click event listener to the item
        console.log(this.innerText); // console.log() the item's text.
    });
}
```

Also read the following MDN documentations to learn about the used functions:

- [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)
- [getElementByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName)
- [Loops and iterations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration)
- [innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText)

Happy learning!